# Insert data frame on a single table of a data Base using R and ORDBC

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rodbc

how could i insert a full dataframe into a single table of mysql database

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
`iddata` int(11) NOT NULL,
`x` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`y` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`iddata`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

this is my R code :

```
file <- paste("C:\\Users\\zakaria\\Documents\\RDMZ\\test_rr.csv")
table <- read.table(file,sep=",",header=T)
channel <-odbcConnect(dsn="RSQL",uid="root",pwd="toor")
x <-table[,1]
y<-table[,2]



data<-sqlQuery(channel,paste("INSERT INTO 'data'.'dbwin'('x','y') VALUES (", x,", ", y, ");"))
sqlQuery(channel,data)
```

i have this error

```
[1] "42000 1064 [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.17]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '42000 1064 [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.17]You have an error in your S' at line 1"                   
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect '42000 1064 [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.17]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''data'.'dbwin'('x','y') VALUES ( 0.708007801949862 ,  84 )' at line 1'"
```

thank u for your help

Comment: I'll bet if you looked at your `paste` statement output in isolation, you'd find that it isn't valid SQL. You might find it easier to use `sqlSave` or `sqlUpdate`.

Comment: I'm glad. Write an answer yourself that describes exactly what worked for you, and then (after a short waiting period) you can accept that answer, which will indicate that this issue is solved.

Comment: i just add this line 'sqlSave(channel, table, tablename = "rr")' and i remove this 2 line 'data<-sqlQuery(channel,paste("INSERT INTO 'data'.'dbwin'('RR','HR') VALUES (", x,", ", y, ");"))
sqlQuery(channel,data)'

Comment: Please edit your question so that it contains _only_ your question. Place _answers_ in the space for answers below. Is `sqlSave` the solution? Put that in an answer. Leave the original code in your question.

Comment: If you want to use sql for this, what is `dbwin`? Also what are `RR` and `HH`? It looks like you are trying to put values from the `table` into columns named `RR` and `HH`, but there are not such columns in your `CREATE TABLE`?? Shouldn't the sql be something like `INSERT INTO data (X,Y) VALUES ("x-value","y-value")`, remembering that the argument to the VALUE clause must be quoted.

Comment: @jlhoward i juste redit my code,i'm little bit confused ,sorry for that mistake ,Dbwin is my the name of my database ,x and y  are the columns of my table ,for the query yeah it's like in your comment but i would like that x-value to be the list of the values x of mytable ,for value-y also.

Comment: The database is usually identified in the dsn part of the `odbcConnect(...)` statement - e.g., it's part of the `channel` specification. So you should not need to specify it in the sql. Can you try something like `data<-sqlQuery(channel,"INSERT INTO data (x,y) VALUES (\"A\",\"B\");")` as an experiment?

Comment: @jlhoward this query works

Comment: OK I re-posted an answer. Take a look, but @joran's comment sums it up - use `sqlSave(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with @joran's suggestion: use `sqlSave(...)`, which is designed for this.

There are a couple of reasons your code is not working. One problem is that you define `x` and `y` as `varchar`, but you don't quote the strings in the sql.

```
x<-"A"
y<-"B"
sql <- paste("INSERT INTO 'data'.'dbwin'('x','y') VALUES (", x,", ", y, ");")
cat(sql)
# INSERT INTO 'data'.'dbwin'('x','y') VALUES ( A ,  B );
```

Rather, use this:

```
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO 'data'.'dbwin'('x','y') VALUES (\"", x,"\", \"", y, "\");")
cat(sql)
# INSERT INTO 'data'.'dbwin'('x','y') VALUES ("A", "B");
```

The second is that you do not need to include the database name in the sql, since that information is embedded in the connection. Rather, use something like:

```
sql <- "INSERT INTO data (x,y) values (\"A\",\"B\")"
```

Finally, and most important, this form of INSERT adds *one row* to the database table, so you cannot use vectors for x and y (as your code does). Here's a work-around:

```
## not tested
apply(table[,1:2], 1, function(values) {
  x    <- values[1]
  y    <- values[2]
  sql  <- paste0("INSERT INTO data (x,y) VALUES (\"", x,"\", \"", y, "\");")
  data <-sqlQuery(channel,sql)
  sqlQuery(channel,data)
})
```

This will (should..) execute an sql INSERT for each row of `table`. It's likely to be slower then `sqlSave(...)` though.

Finally, you don't need two calls to `sqlQuery(...)`.

Comment: @jihoward no it does not work also ,the problem is when i try to run sqlQuery(channel,sql) i have the same error,sqlsave works for me but i would like to use paste with sqlQuery because i will read a lot of csv files and do the insertion in a single table

Comment: @jihoward ,your function gives to me this error  :Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 'getCharCE' must be called on a CHARSXP